# Laravel pagination doesn't display meta data in json response

Tags: laravel, pagination

I couldn't figure it out why but, when I use `->pagination()` on the data, meta data doesn't display in the endpoint.

[image: it's response]

and in the controller;

```
    $bridals = Bridal::with(["plans" => function($query){
        $query->orderBy("plans.plan_price");
    }])->paginate(10);

    $group = $bridals
    ->groupBy(function ($bridal) {
        return $bridal->place_name;
    });

    return response()->json($group);
```

By the way I can reach the next page by adding `?page=1`, 2,3,4 etc. end of the endpoint path. But i can't see the meta data in the response. Anyone know what is the reason, what am I missing here?

Comment: That's because by calling a `collection` method on it, you are mutating it and returning exactly that, a collection. Instead, move the `groupBy` method into your query so that the `toJson` interface can be applied on the `Paginator` instance.

Comment: yes, thank you for pointing it out. it solved the problem.  @Ohgodwhy